# Formatting div table

Tags: css

I am just looking for any recommendations to help me format this div table properly. The Set section of the table does not extend the full length. I have included a photo of what it currently looks like.I have tried playing around with display options for the rows and cells but nothing seems to give me the result I am looking for.

```
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head> 

<style>
    .CategoryTable 
    {
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        display: table;
        vertical-align: middle;
        border-top: 1px solid black;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }

    .CategoryTable-Row 
    {
        display: table-row;
        width: auto;
        max-width: 800px;
        border-top: 1px solid black;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .CategoryTable > .CategoryTable-Row:last-child
    {
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }

    div.CategoryTable-Row:nth-child(even)
    {
        background-color: #e6ffe6;
    }

    .CategoryTable-Row:first-child
    {
        border-top: 1px solid black;
    }

    .CategoryTable-Cell
    {
        word-wrap: normal;
        display: table-cell;
        width: auto;
        min-width: 300px;
        height: 100%;
        border-right: 1px solid black;
    }

    .CategoryTable-Label
    {
        text-align: center;
        border-left: 1px solid black;
        max-width: 490px;
    }

    .CategoryTable-Field
    {
        max-width: 290px;
    }

    .CategoryTable-Set
    {
        display: table-row;
        width: auto;
        min-width: 300px;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .CategoryTable-SetHeader {
        width: auto;
        background-color: #008000;
        color: white;
        height: 20px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-bottom: none;
        border-top: none;
    }

    .CategoryTable-SetFooter
    {
        width: auto;
        background-color: #008000;
        border: 1px solid black;
        height: 20px;
        border-bottom: none;
        border-top: none;
    }

    .CategoryTable-DropDown
    {
        cursor: pointer;
    }


</style>


<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
    });

</script>

<div class="CategoryTable">
    <div class="CategoryTable-Row">
        <div class="CategoryTable-Cell CategoryTable-Label">This is a very long title that will span across the entire div. Wrap, or push over, or hide? More text goes here.</div>
        <div class="CategoryTable-Cell CategoryTable-Field"><input class="CategoryTable-Input"></input></div>
    </div>
    <div class="CategoryTable-Row">
        <div class="CategoryTable-Cell CategoryTable-Label">Label</div>
        <div class="CategoryTable-Cell CategoryTable-Field"><input type="checkbox"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="CategoryTable-Row">
        <div class="CategoryTable-Cell CategoryTable-Label">Label</div>
        <div class="CategoryTable-Cell CategoryTable-Field">
            <select class="CategoryTable-DropDown">
                <option value="default">Select Here</option>
                <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                <option value="3">Option 3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="CategoryTable-Row">
        <div class="CategoryTable-Cell CategoryTable-Label">Label</div>
        <div class="CategoryTable-Cell CategoryTable-Field"><input class="CategoryTable-Input"></input></div>
    </div>
    <div class="CategoryTable-Set">
        <div class="CategoryTable-SetHeader">This is a Set</div>
        <div class="CategoryTable-Row">
            <div class="CategoryTable-Cell CategoryTable-Label">Label</div>
            <div class="CategoryTable-Cell CategoryTable-Field"><input type="checkbox"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="CategoryTable-Row">
            <div class="CategoryTable-Cell CategoryTable-Label">Label</div>
            <div class="CategoryTable-Cell CategoryTable-Field">
                <select class="CategoryTable-DropDown">
                        <option value="default">Select Here</option>
                        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="CategoryTable-Row">
            <div class="CategoryTable-Cell CategoryTable-Label">Label</div>
            <div class="CategoryTable-Cell CategoryTable-Field"><input class="CategoryTable-Input"></input></div>
        </div>
        <div class="CategoryTable-Row">
            <div class="CategoryTable-Cell CategoryTable-Label">Label</div>
            <div class="CategoryTable-Cell CategoryTable-Field"><input type="checkbox"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="CategoryTable-SetFooter"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="CategoryTable-Row">
        <div class="CategoryTable-Cell CategoryTable-Label">Label</div>
        <div class="CategoryTable-Cell CategoryTable-Field">
            <select class="CategoryTable-DropDown">
                    <option value="default">Select Here</option>
                    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="CategoryTable-Row">
        <div class="CategoryTable-Cell CategoryTable-Label">Label</div>
        <div class="CategoryTable-Cell CategoryTable-Field"><input class="CategoryTable-Input"></input></div>
    </div>
    <div class="CategoryTable-Row">
        <div class="CategoryTable-Cell CategoryTable-Label">Label</div>
        <div class="CategoryTable-Cell CategoryTable-Field"><input type="checkbox"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="CategoryTable-Row">
        <div class="CategoryTable-Cell CategoryTable-Label">Label</div>
        <div class="CategoryTable-Cell CategoryTable-Field">
            <select class="CategoryTable-DropDown">
                <option value="default">Select Here</option>
                <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                <option value="3">Option 3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="CategoryTable-Row">
        <div class="CategoryTable-Cell CategoryTable-Label">Label</div>
        <div class="CategoryTable-Cell CategoryTable-Field"><input class="CategoryTable-Input"></input></div>
    </div>
    <div class="CategoryTable-Row">
        <div class="CategoryTable-Cell CategoryTable-Label">Label</div>
        <div class="CategoryTable-Cell CategoryTable-Field"><input type="checkbox"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="CategoryTable-Row">
        <div class="CategoryTable-Cell CategoryTable-Label">Label</div>
        <div class="CategoryTable-Cell CategoryTable-Field">
            <select class="CategoryTable-DropDown">
                    <option value="default">Select Here</option>
                    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Table Example Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiAxz.png)

Comment: What is is supposed to look like? I would use flexbox but I understand it is an actual table so semantically you should probly use a table but flexbox would make it much easier to handle the layout

Comment: @StefanBob The section where it says "this is a set" is supposed to extend the full length of the table. The label sections should all line up and the input fields should all line up, it should look like a normal rectangular table.

Comment: @BreeSavard is this important to create table with "div" may be you should use <td> and <tr>?

Comment: @EDWIN I would if I could, there are issues with screen readers when using tables so I have to completely avoid them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, one of the easiest solution here:

Change your

```
.CategoryTable 
    {
        display: table;
    }
```

To

```
.CategoryTable 
    {
        display: table-caption;
    }
```

And your

```
.CategoryTable-Set
    {
        display: table-row;
    }
```

To

```
.CategoryTable-Set
    {
        display: block;
    }
```

It will collapse your table a little bit, but it still looks pretty well, you can check it here: https://jsfiddle.net/z719apcn/

And one more tip, you have a lot of СSS-code that does nothing. You should remove some lines and look at the changes - if there are no changes, then this line was not needed.

Comment: This is good progress but unfortunately does not work as expected with IE. Thanks for the tips!